# Analog Multiplier with MOSFET - Implementation not working

Tags: mosfet, analog, multiplier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffatfE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am using the above circuit to multiply BAT1 and V2, the circuit analysis tells me the output voltage Vm1 should be BAT1xV2x2xKxR1 This works by keeping the transistors in the triode region thus the gate voltage controls the resistance between V2 and ground. My problem is that the circuit implementation doesn't seem to multiply correctly both inputs.

The LM741 are connected to +15 and -15 accordingly.

I would like to know what is wrong with the circuit, if you can, please help.

Comment: It really isn't clear what you're trying to accomplish here. Vgs on the MOSFETs is +9.0V +/-50mV, so both of them are turned on fairly hard. You're basically going to get their minimum Rds(on). If you want to operate the MOSFETs in a subthreshold region, BAT3 needs to be much less.

Comment: Where did you come across this idea?

Comment: Hello, thanks for sharing. The idea of BAT3 is to keep Vgs(BATs)-2V larger than Vds (V2). So that the transistor operates in ohmic region. Analysing the circuit as per the OpAmp analysis yields the VM1 formula above, when the MOSFET is in Ohmic. I do think I have a problem with MOS polarization.

Comment: Andy, I found the idea here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Electronics/Analog_multipliers I searched a bit more and found a circuit similar to above, then I did the pen and paper analysis, so that I may use transistors and OpAmp that I have available.

Comment: I am afraid to call this an answer but either way: I changed the LM741 Vee to +-30 and changed the R to 2k, I now get acceptable multiplication for input under 150mx200m (V2xBAT1) I also lowered BAT3 to 3V. Thanks to everyone that helped.

Answer (score 1):

What you have drawn bears little resemblance to the circuit you have linked to: -

[image]

Note how the output from the lower op-amp feeds back to both gates on the MOSFETs - this is fundamentally important to how the multiplier works in keeping stuff relatively linear - M2 is presumed to behave exactly like M1 but without the feedback your circuit will not behave correctly at all.

Are you sure you know what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The circuit I am actually using is the one from page 16, slide 32 here: http://www-elec.inaoep.mx/~materesa/pdf/DCIAII_11/Tema8_11.pdf I simulated the circuited you pasted as well, but I couldn't get it to work either.

Comment: bat3 voltage level is too high for your circuit to work and it was not clear that the 50mV sources were acting in tandem and opposition. 100R as feedback on the opamp is too low as well.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Hi, I tried that circuit implmentation myself and it did not work. So, I came up with one myself.[image]

The basic unit of the multiplier is shown in the simpler diagram. The Vout equation is given by this:

Vout = 5/8*V1*(4-V1/2+V2)

I used a sequential series of op-amp arithmetic to yield the result Vout = v1*v2. If you look at the above equation you can re-arrange it such that:

8/5*Vout - 4V1 + (V1^2)/2 = V1*V2

Thus, the simple multiplier diagram gets several more components added to it, and the result is an actual multiplier that works, although with quite a lot of components, I agree.

The input value V1 and V2 must be between 0 to -4V. As a result the circuit actually does division with values between 0 to -1V.

I hope you enjoy this circuit. I simulated it using iCircuit on my iPad.

Andrew